# When trying to call a DLL in java gives the error: java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access

Tags: java, jersey, jna

im using Java + Jersey + JNA(https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna/4.5.2)
to acess a DLL file with was made in delphi.

My operational system is Windowns 10, 64bits.
The dll was generated in 64bits.

Im just trying to access the DLL method in java.

Java`s code is:

**DllSimples.java**

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public interface DllSimples extends Library{

    String testar(); 
}
```

**TesteService.java**

```
public Response chamaDll() {

    DllSimples calculadora = (DllSimples)
              Native.loadLibrary("teste", DllSimples.class);

    String parametro = calculadora.testar();

    MensageiroDTO mensagem = new MensageiroDTO(parametro);
    return Response.ok(mensagem).build();
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:432)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.rethrow(ResponseWriter.java:278)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.failure(ResponseWriter.java:260)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:460)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:285)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

**NOTE: THE DLL WAS TESTED IN DELPHI LANGUAGE PREVIOUSLY AND IT IS WORKING.**

Comment: Don’t reload the DLL every time you call the function, just store the interface statically.

Comment: Please show the function declaration and parameter documentation of the Delphi function.

Comment: Hello my friends, i have found the problem. I do not use pchar variable in delphi, i used string. So, String in java and Delphi does not work together. The Variables types of them must be compatible. The message error is strange and does not corresponds the real problem. Thanks for your time.